# Recover /var/www/html

Tags: 14.04, apache2

So I made a huge mistake and accidently removed /var/www/html and cant restart apache2.. is the content of /var/www/html static or can I copy it from somewhere. Ive just started today with installing my first ubuntu 14.04 webserver (took me alot of hours) and have not made a backup because I was finishing the installation proces. I also looked for an command to fix packages, I tried sudo apt-get but it didn't fix the /var/www/html folder unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have just started hopefully there is no important file in `/var/www/html`.
You can simply make this directory by following command.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html
```

Additionaly you reconfigure apache2 by following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apache2
```

If you need to recover the deleted files follow this thread on [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Are there any docs or something that describe file contents, couldn't find any of them.